# Changing value of a text node

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to get to the second node of an element. Here is the function I am using:

```
window.onload = function() {
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-gb")

for (i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    console.log(list[i]);
    var x = list[i].childNodes[1];
    console.log(x);
    var x = x.nodeValue.slice(1);
};
};
```

`console.log(list[i])` returns

```
<td>
<a href="www.xxx.com">link</a>
0 text node I want to edit via script
<span>something</span>
</td>
```

`console.log(x)` returns string `0 text node I want to edit via script`

How do I get rid of the `0`? Slice method doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Which element has class `foo`? (This is clearly example code; thanks for not dumping 2 pages of code here)

Comment: Hi, I was missing the {} in for loop which was missing the original issue. Now I struggle with slicing the string in the node..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` block is not wrapped with `{...}`, so the actual loop is running only on the `console.log(list[i]);` line.

Your `i` variable is currently equal `list.length`, so `list[i]` is `undefined`, and you are trying to get the `childNodes` of `undefined`.

Here is the change:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("foo")

  for (i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    console.log(list[i]);
    var x = list[i].childNodes[1];
    console.log(x);
  }
};
```

```html
<td>
<a href="www.xxx.com">link</a>
text node I want to edit via script
<span>something</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. How do I then change the value of the text node? I would like to slice off the first character of the string...

Comment: Content - i.e. in the example above, I would like to erase the '0' at the beginning of '0 text node I want to edit via script'.

Comment: `list[i].childNodes[1].textContent = list[i].childNodes[1].textContent.slice(1)` (in case this node contains only text..)